# $('div[class^="ii gt"]') works in chrome not firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am working on a Firefox extension. In Google Chrome, I get elements by using:
`var element = $('div[class^="ii gt"]')`
It returns an object.  I then get the first element's first child using `element[0].children[0]` which works fine.

But in Firefox, on same HTML page using the above code returns an object, but the object does not contain any child elements.  I also checked the length which is 0.  In addition, I tried  `$("*[class^='ii gt']") and $("*[class*='ii gt']")`  which both return 0 length.

What is the problem?  How can it be resolved?

**Note:** The class of the `<div>` contains dynamic prefix names like "ii gt aaa" and "ii gt bbb".

Updated:i just try to using the whole class name using `document.getElementsByClassName('ii gt m1485f8bb9d512968 adP adO')[0].innerHTML`.it not works.but using `content.document.getElementsByClassName('ii gt m1485f8bb9d512968 adP adO')[0].innerHTML` it works.so what is the problem?Anyone know about it?

Comment: Could you show us the html markup?
It seems to work here in Firefox : http://jsfiddle.net/3o287520/

Comment: In what context is your Firefox code executed?

Comment: @paa :Gmail inbox mail context.

Comment: By cintext I mean if the code is part of a content script, or `main.js` or something else.

Comment: Judging by the update, your extension is a XUL one. Your code executes in the content of the ChromeWindow, that's why you have to use `content` to access the `HTMLWindow`.

Comment: @ paa: so,how can i get the elements using class starting name?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some code. Am I right that your extension is XUL?

Answer (score 3):

You could just use `$(".ii.gt")`. This will select all elements having both classes, and it will be a lot faster than using the regex as selector (`prop^=*` is via regex).

The order of classes should not matter, that would make very difficult code. Just imagine, you come back after a year, add a class and eveything stops working, just by adding the class?

Comment: thanks Martijn.but it not works.i tried var getclass = $(".ii.gt"); and var classelement = getclass[0];.but it returns null in firefox.

Comment: i just try using the whole class name using document.getElementsByClassName('ii gt m1485f8bb9d512968 adP adO')[0].innerHTML.it not works.but using content.document.getElementsByClassName('ii gt m1485f8bb9d512968 adP adO')[0].innerHTML it works.so whats the problem?

Comment: I dont know if `getElementsByClassName` takes multiple classes. you want `querySelector` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using filtering works better?

```js
// selector
$('[data-result=1]')
  .html('length children div.ii.gt*: '
        + $('div').filter( 
             function (i, el) {return /^ii gt/i.test(el.className);})
          .children().length);
```

```css
[data-result] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>some div</div>

<div class="ii gtsomething">
   <div>child div.ii.gt</div>
   <div>second child div.ii.gt</div>
</div>

<div data-result="1"></div>
```

Comment: @Kooilnc : See my updated question.how can i get the XUL elements using class prefix name?

Answer (score 0):

here i have solve my issue.thank u guys.

```
var getDocument = content.document;

var composeDecrypt = $(getDocument).find('div[class^="ii gt"]');

var originalContent = composeDecrypt[0].children[0].innerHTML;
```